# Xamarin forms: Issue with multiple events click on same day in XamForms.Controls.Calendar

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using `XamForms.Controls.Calendar` for showing events on the calendar. I have give color for special dates on the calendar using the following code:

```cs
private void AddSpecialDateWithList(List<events> list)
{
    List<SpecialDate> newList = new List<SpecialDate>();
    foreach (events model in list)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.end))
        {
            string date = model.start;
            int index = date.IndexOf('T');
            if (index > 0)
            {
                date = date.Substring(0, index);
            }
            var newDate = AddDate(DateTime.Parse(date), model);
            newList.Add(newDate);
            newEventsList.Add(model);
        }
        else
        {
            string startDate = model.start;
            int startIndex = startDate.IndexOf('T');
            if (startIndex > 0)
            {
                startDate = startDate.Substring(0, startIndex);
            }

            string endDate = model.end;
            int endIndex = endDate.IndexOf('T');
            if (endIndex > 0)
            {
                endDate = endDate.Substring(0, endIndex);
            }
            List<DateTime> dates = GetDatesBetween(DateTime.Parse(startDate), DateTime.Parse(endDate));
            for (int i = 0; i < dates.Count; i++)
            {
                var newDate = AddDate(dates[i], model);
                newList.Add(newDate);
                newEventsList.Add(model);
            }
        }
    }
    calendar.SpecialDates = newList;
}

private SpecialDate AddDate(DateTime dateTime, events model)
{
    SpecialDate newDate = new SpecialDate(dateTime)
    {
        Selectable = true,
        BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#fec208"),
        TextColor = Color.White
    };
    return newDate;
}

public List<DateTime> GetDatesBetween(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    List<DateTime> allDates = new List<DateTime>();
    for (DateTime date = startDate; date <= endDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
        allDates.Add(date);
    return allDates;
}
```

I have also enabled clicked event for special dates:

```cs
private async void calendar_DateClicked(object sender, DateTimeEventArgs e)
{
    int num = 0;
    var specialList = calendar.SpecialDates;
    var date = e.DateTime;
    selectedEventsList.Clear();
    foreach (SpecialDate specialDate in specialList)
    {
        if (specialDate.Date.Year == date.Year && specialDate.Date.Month == date.Month && specialDate.Date.Day == date.Day)
        {
            events model = new events();
            model = newEventsList[num];
            selectedEventsList.Add(model);
        }
        else
        {
            num++;
        }
    }

    if (selectedEventsList.Count == 1)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Alert", "successs.", "Ok");
    }
    else
    {
        eventTitleList.Clear();
        for (int j = 0; j < selectedEventsList.Count; j++)
        {
            eventTitleList.Add(selectedEventsList[j].title);
        }
        string action = await DisplayActionSheet(null, "Cancel", null, eventTitleList.ToArray());
        for (int k = 0; k < eventTitleList.Count; k++)
        {
            if (action == eventTitleList[k])
            {
                //next page
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When multiple events coming on the same day I need to show the events as a pop-up window. Then the user is able to select the event from the pop-up and go to the details page. I have implemented this on the above code, but sometimes duplicates events are showing on the pop-up window.

I have created a sample project for reproducing the issue. In the sample project, on 7May, the events are Chemistry Assignment and English Project. But Chemistry Assignment is showing duplicate. 10 may events are Chemistry Assignment and Physics, but showing Chemistry Assignment and English Project. I checked this lot of times, but didn't find the reason behind this.

Comment: I have removed a link to Google Drive that no longer worked. The error from Google was "the file is in that owner's trash bin".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error caused by that the `newEventsList` do not get the correct index.

**Change the code in `calendar_DateClicked` event from:**

```
foreach (SpecialDate specialDate in specialList)
    {
        if (specialDate.Date.Year == date.Year && specialDate.Date.Month == date.Month && specialDate.Date.Day == date.Day)
        {
            events model = new events();
            model = newEventsList[num];
            selectedEventsList.Add(model);
        }
        else
        {
            num++;
        }
    }
```

**To:**

```
 foreach (SpecialDate specialDate in specialList)
          {
             if (specialDate.Date.Year == date.Year && specialDate.Date.Month == date.Month && specialDate.Date.Day == date.Day)
            {    
                events model = new events();
                model = newEventsList[num];
                selectedEventsList.Add(model);
            }

                num++;

        }
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]
[image]

Comment: what change you have done the code in the calendar_DateClicked event? Looks the new code you have suggested is the same as old code. Could you please check, maybe an issue when you paste. The screenshots you have added are right.

Comment: That is the code i want to change. I delete the `else` statement and increase the `num` count each time. After that, you could get the correct index for `newEventsList `.